# Turning off shift after typing key

Tags: java, android, keyboard, shift

Below is the code I'm using to add an `OnKeyboardActionListener` to my `KeyboardView`. (For the sake of brevity, I've omitted the required overridden methods that I've left empty.)

```
keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

    private void shiftOn(boolean on) {
        System.out.println("Shifting " + (on ? "on" : "off"));
        keyboard.setShifted(on);
        shiftKey.icon = keyboard.isShifted() ? shiftLockDrawable : shiftDrawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

        Editable editable = editText.getEditableText();
        int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();

        if (primaryCode == SHIFT) {
            shiftOn(!keyboard.isShifted());
        } else {
            if (primaryCode == DELETE) {
                if (editable != null && selectionStart > 0) {
                    editable.delete(selectionStart - 1, selectionStart);
                }
            } else {
                editable.insert(selectionStart, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }

            shiftOn(false);
        }
    }
});
```

**The problem**

When I press the shift key, everything goes as expected; both the key's icon and the state of "shiftedness" changes.

However, when I press any other key (which is supposed to turn shift off), the state of shiftedness changes to off, but the icon doesn't change to the unshifted version. I experience the same problem when using text instead of icons.

I've tried calling `postInvalidate()` on my `KeyboardView` but to no avail.

Here's a [video](http://tinypic.com/r/21d1uzq/5) that highlights my problem.

Comment: is your shiftOn() method working. I mean are you getting the log of Shifting On/Off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code to the end of the `shiftOn` method:

```
keyboard.invalidateKey(SHIFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the redrawing of the shift key is attached to the actual input event. Can you, instead of changing the shiftKeyIcon simulate a shift key press in code? You just generate an additional shift key press event when another key is pressed.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I had thought about key press simulation as a possibility, but how would I do so? I don't see such a method in any of the relavent classes.

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is a problem in `shiftOn()`. I don't exactly know what shiftLockDrawable and shiftDrawable do, but maybe the following code works

```
private void shiftOn(boolean on) {
    System.out.println("Shifting " + (on ? "on" : "off"));
    shiftKey.icon = (on ? shiftLockDrawable : shiftDrawable);
    keyboard.setShifted(on);
}
```

If this doesn't work or if this isn't what you want, could you maybe provide more information?

Comment: shiftLockDrawable is the icon for when shift is on, and shiftDrawable is the icon for when shift is off. This didn't fix the problem, although it's probably better to use the `on` variable as you did instead of `isShifted()`.

Comment: I ran a test, using the `shiftDrawable` and `shiftLockDrawable` as a `String`. That worked fine, so the bug isn't in this part of the code. What Class do you use for the icons? I think that this class doesn't redraw the icon you showed in the video, even though the variable changed. Does the icon class have a redraw method?

If this is not the problem, have you tried a step by step debug? Modern Java IDE's like Netbeans and Eclipse give you the possability to debug your program.

Comment: They are Drawable objects

Comment: On [this]() site I found the specification of `Drawable`. There I found the method `invalidateSelf()`. If this is the right class, could you try to call this method after you change the state of the Drawable object?